# Using .htaccess to Deny All Except from a Specific Referring Page

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way to restrict access to a folder (using .htaccess or another method) such that all requests are blocked except those coming from a specific path on another domain?

I've tried something like this, but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !hosting_domain\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !referring_domain\.com/path/to/referrer [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

Basically, I want to end up with a scenario where a user goes to a certain page, and then can only access restricted files from that page.

More details...

- The .htaccess file is one level higher than the folder that the "protected" files are in.
- There are no other .htaccess files.
- Direct access is currently being allowed by browsing to the file directly.
- The only other non-commented out code in the file is the following.

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php 
 <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
  suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php70/lib
 </IfModule>`

Comment: This certainly is possible, but not robust at all, since obviously anyone interested in your "restricted files" can set the referrer header to whatever seems suitable. So this is more a form of obfuscation, not of securing a system.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm not 100% concerned with security, but I'm just trying to add something that's more than nothing.  Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: Your approach points into the right direction. I am afraid we cannot help much here, since we have no idea about your actual request situation. Your "but it's not working" does not help here, it is by far to vague.

Comment: I suggest you enable rewrite logging. Check the documentation of the rewriting module you are using here to learn how to. That documentation is of excellent quality, as typical for OpenSource software, and comes with great examples. Rewrite logging allows to understand in detail what is actually going on inside the rewriting engine.

Comment: "it's not working" - in what way exactly? Is everything block? Is nothing blocked? Have you confirmed that the `Referer` header is being sent with the request from the other domain? Where is this `.htaccess` file? Is it in the folder you wish to restrict access to? Do you have any other directives in this `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: @MrWhite: Thanks for your comment.  I've added more detail.  I don't know how to confirm that `Referer` is being sent.  I control both domains though, so I should be able to force this.... right?

Comment: So, are requests from the other domain being blocked? "Direct access is currently being allowed by browsing to the file directly." - Yes, that is permitted by those directives. Do you not want that to happen?

Comment: @MrWhite: I only want the files available via the referring link I specify.  No browsing to them, or getting some kind of other link to them.  I know referrer can be spoofed, and this is "security by obscurity", but it's what I'm looking at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !hosting_domain\.net [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !referring_domain\.com/path/to/referrer [NC]
> RewriteRule .? - [F]
> ```
>
> I only want the files available via the referring link I specify. **No browsing to them**

If you don't want to allow "direct access" then you need to remove the first `RewriteCond` directive that checks that the `Referer` is not empty. On direct requests the `Referer` is empty.

And if you *only* want the resource being accessed by the *referring domain* then you should remove the 2nd condition also.

You can also be more specific with the referring domain and include the full absolute URL. In other words:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://referring_domain\.com/path/to/referrer$
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

I've also removed the `NC` flag - the `Referer` should be the "exact" URL - correct case. (If it is set at all.)

Comment: Maybe I'm doing this wrong.  I have...

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/subdomainfolder/folders/referring_page.php$
RewriteRule .? - [F]

What am I missing?

Comment: The formatting got messed on the comment.  It won't allow line breaks.  Sorry.

Comment: It should be exactly as written in my answer (plus the `RewriteEngine On` directive). `RewriteBase` is not required here. So, what's the problem? Are these files still accessible directly? Links from the referring domain not blocked? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have other `.htaccess` files? Is the `.htaccess` file being processed? What `Referer` is being passed in the HTTP Request header from the browser?

Comment: The only thing I have in the .htaccess file is  `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^example\.com/subdomainfolder/folders/referring_page.php$
RewriteRule .? - [F]`  I'm getting a 403 forbidden when "grabbing" that file via the `example\.com/subdomainfolder/folders/referring_page.php` page.

Comment: FYI: Chrome inspector says "Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade" on the file that's being forbidden.  I really don't know much about editing .htaccess files directly, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: "`!^example\.com/subdom`" - You need to include the protocol here, ie. `http://` or `https://` - the absolute URL. "Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade" - that's the _default_ Referrer-Policy that most browsers set, which means that no `Referer` header will be set when navigating from HTTPS to HTTP. I would assume both your sites are HTTPS, so this shouldn't be an issue. (?)

Comment: "Chrome inspector says..." - you need to look for the `Referer` HTTP request header below. If it's not there then the browser has not sent it (usually the Referrer-Policy is the issue, but users can suppress/change the `Referer` with browser plugins if they wish.)

Comment: That may be the issue.  One site is https, and the other is http (currently).  I also see that there isn't a `Referer` entry under "Headers" in the Chrome inspector.  I may need to look for another solution to this problem.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You can override the [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) on the specific pages of the referring site in order to send the appropriate `Referer` header if you wish. (But note the potential security/privacy implications associated with this, if relevant.)